# Filtering rows from list in R; error while using %in%?

Tags: r

Assume the following as an input

```
library(tidyverse)

Data <- structure(list(column = c("S1", "S2", "S3"), Val1 = c(11, 22, 
33), Val2 = c(44, 55, 66)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

Key <- tibble(Key = c("S1","S2"))
```

To give

```
A tibble: 3 × 3
  column  Val1  Val2
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 S1        11    44
2 S2        22    55
3 S3        33    66
```

When I do a

```
Data %>% filter(column %in% Key)
```

I get zilch

```
 A tibble: 0 × 3
 3 variables: column <chr>, Val1 <dbl>, Val2 <dbl>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `… %in% Key$Key)` and see if that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a vector of `Keys`

```r
library(tidyverse)

Key <- c("S1","S2")

Data %>% 
  filter(column %in% Key)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   column  Val1  Val2
#>   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 S1        11    44
#> 2 S2        22    55
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>